# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using CCSkeletonAnimation

Tags: cocos2d-x-2.x

I'm new in cocos2d-x. When I put these code in `init()` method

```
CCSkeletonAnimation* skeletonNode = CCSkeletonAnimation::createWithFile("spine/miner.json", "spine/miner.atlas");
skeletonNode->setAnimation("run",true);
addchild(skeletonNode);
```

, it throws out an error message

```
    void CCObject::release(void)
{
    CCAssert(m_uReference > 0, "reference count should greater than 0");
    --m_uReference;

    if (m_uReference == 0)
    {
        delete this;
    }
}
```

In SpineTest of TestCpp they do the same but no errors. So what exactly cause this error?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This part of your code looks okay. A call to addChild() increments the reference counter. Set a conditional breakpoint in CCObject::release() which breaks if m_uReference == 0 to see who's calling release() for which object.

Comment: I've figured out the problem is that spine runtime packed with my cocos2d-x is out-of-date so that it cannot read the atlas file i've exported.